# Why does WordPress want a 512×512 pixel site icon

Tags: favicon

I get that a site icon needs to be square, but I don't know why it needs to be as large as 512×512 or larger.

Can anyone advise why is this, and/or where that image would be used at a resolution higher than that of a favicon (which I understand to be 48×48px or smaller) and what would be the consequences of using a lower resolution image there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site icon in WordPress is worked as a favicon.

And the knowledge about the favicon is mostly limited to 16×16 or 64×64 pixels. But [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6951351/1743124) shows there's a necessity of a 114×114px favicon for Retina Opera, and a 200×200px favicon for Mobile Opera Speed Dial.

The necessity of such a larger icon is mostly to support retina displays, where it requires larger output, and smaller favicon can get pixelated. This [article by Thomas Fuchs](https://davidwalsh.name/retina-favicons) has a mention of 512×512px retina-ready favicon.

And I found [this article with its comments](https://www.emergeinteractive.com/insights/detail/the-essentials-of-favicons/) stating that:

> 512×512px icon in the web manifest to support browser loading splash screens

Also found mention of other sizes like 192×192px, 228×228px etc.

So, with a maximum 512×512px Site icon, WordPress has all the ease to display it in different devices in different display ratios.

Finally [this WordPress guide](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/27/site-icon/) on using Site icon in WordPress could assist you.