# How to disable cropping of the site icon?

Tags: theme-customizer, favicon

Is it possible to disable the cropping step when adding a site icon via the Theme Customizer in WordPress 5+ (occurred to me in 5.5)?

For me cropping is unnecessary because I always upload a square image in the directions of the recommendations.

That's why this step is not helping me at all, instead is actually causing the following problems:

- It creates an unnecessary copy of the image with a `cropped` prefix.
- For the cropped image it creates a **NEW** attachment.

Thus all the settings I did for the attachment of the un-cropped image are lost and the filename of the site icon will always include this `cropped` prefix.

Is there anyway to fix this without patching the source of this problem?

Comment: Don't you get a option for skip cropping in site icon?

Comment: @PradiptaSarkar no not anymore. I remember in older version it was present.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/372450/why-does-wordpress-want-a-512%C3%97512-pixel-site-icon

Comment: Yah the weirder part is even if you upload an image that is exactly 512x512, WordPress still crops it regardless and creates a new file...

Answer (score 1):

To force the site icon to be a specific attachment you can use the `wp-admin/options.php` page and search for the `site_icon` label then change the value of the field to the attachment ID you would like it to be.

Of course this also can be done via SQL, with a query somewhat similar to:

```
update wp_options set option_value=123 where option_name='site_icon';
```

Note that this only works once you initialized the `site_icon` option.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325151/how-can-a-default-site-icon-be-set-in-customizer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's still no fix to this issue. WordPress will still crop the image even though your favicon is 512px x 512px.

To solve this issue, I installed Elementor and updated my site icon via the Site Settings. It doesn't crop the image and you won't have to deal with an additional file in your media library with the `cropped` prefix.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/260740)